# Temperature dependence of elastic collision of gas molecules with the wall

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

The following is written in my textbook and I quote it here

> The collisions of gas molecules with the walls are elastic of the temperature of the walls is same as the temperature of the gas.

I am unable to figure out the reason behind this and I need your help here. According to me the collisions will deviate from being elastic only if temperature difference is too high to cause deformations leading to change in potential energy and that is not the case here.

Please guide me as these concepts are new for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the gas and walls are of a different temperature then they will exchange energy until they equilibrate with each other. This means the gas molecules, upon bouncing off the walls, will (on average) either lose or gain energy depending on the temperature differential. And thus the collisions will generally be inelastic.

Answer (score 1):

If the system is in thermal equilibrium, the temperature of the gas and the wall is the same. In other words, no energy is (on average) transferred from the gas to the wall (or opposite). This implies that the gas molecules does not change their kinetic energy after a collision. This is the definition of elastic collisions: The total kinetic energy is the same before and after the coliison

In elastic collisions, the total kinetic energy is the same before and after the collisions.